# Fill a list with parts until the sum of part volumes reaches a capacity, then create new list and fill

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a list of parts with masses and want to create batches of parts. The batches have volume capacities as boundary.

Whenever putting the next part in a batch would exceed that batches capacity, a new batch should be created. The capacity of a batch is not the length or amount of entries but a fixed volume that the sum of volumes of parts assigned can not exceed.

```
    for part in partlist:
       if cap - part_volume >= 0:
           batch.append(part)
           cap -= part_volume
       else:
           # create new_batch
           new_batch.append(part)
```

Comment: SyntaxError - missing : after some lines. What is your problem? Seems the algorythm - if implemented okish - should work.

Comment: The problem is that I have to dynamically create new batches every time the current one is full.
How many batches I will need is not known beforehand - and I think I should somehow give unique names to the lists(batches) i create.
Like Batch1, Batch2, Batch3... etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Non-Class answer, idea same as above:

```
from random import randint 

# 2nd number is volume
things = [(randint(1,100), randint(2,10)) for _ in range(30)]

batchmaxsize = 20

# add one empty container
containers = [[]]

for t in things:
    mass, volume = t
    totalvol = sum(v for m,v in containers[-1])
    if totalvol + volume > batchmaxsize:
        containers[-1].append(f"Used {totalvol} out of {batchmaxsize}")
        containers.append([])
    containers[-1].append(t)

containers[-1].append(f"Used {totalvol} out of {batchmaxsize}")
print(*containers, sep="\n")
```

Output:

```
[(59, 7), (27, 7), 'Used 14 out of 20']
[(43, 10), (49, 10), 'Used 20 out of 20']
[(98, 6), (1, 10), 'Used 16 out of 20']
[(83, 10), (78, 8), 'Used 18 out of 20']
[(75, 8), (75, 5), 'Used 13 out of 20']
[(100, 8), (9, 8), 'Used 16 out of 20']
[(25, 10), (14, 10), 'Used 20 out of 20']
[(30, 8), (31, 9), 'Used 17 out of 20']
[(18, 4), (51, 3), (94, 5), (3, 7), 'Used 19 out of 20']
[(61, 10), (12, 6), 'Used 16 out of 20']
[(54, 9), (39, 4), 'Used 13 out of 20']
[(100, 8), (54, 5), (72, 4), 'Used 17 out of 20']
[(21, 6), (52, 10), (9, 2), 'Used 16 out of 20']
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to "name" batches, stuff them into a list:

```
class Thing:
    def __init__(self, mass, volume):
        self.mass = mass
        self.volume = volume 
    def __str__(self):
        return f"(M: {self.mass} V:{self.volume})" 

class Container:
    def __init__(self, volume = 20):
        self.volume = volume
        self.things = []
    def add(self, t):
        self.things.append(t)
    def space_left(self):
        return self.volume - sum(t.volume for t in self.things)
    def fits(self, t):
        return self.space_left() - t.volume >= 0 
    def __str__(self):
        return f"[{' | '.join(str(t) for t in self.things)}] Empty: {self.space_left()}"
```

Some test data:

```
from random import randint 

things = [Thing(randint(1,100), randint(2,10)) for _ in range(30)]

# add one empty container
containers = [Container()]

for t in things:
    # check if it fits into last container´, if not create new empty one
    # and add to end of list
    if not containers[-1].fits(t):
        containers.append(Container())
    # add thing to container at end of list
    containers[-1].add(t)

print(*containers, sep="\n")
```

Output:

```
[(M: 4 V:8) | (M: 62 V:7) | (M: 24 V:4)] Empty: 1
[(M: 2 V:10) | (M: 51 V:5)] Empty: 5
[(M: 81 V:6) | (M: 32 V:8)] Empty: 6
[(M: 3 V:9) | (M: 58 V:7)] Empty: 4
[(M: 87 V:6) | (M: 23 V:3) | (M: 90 V:2) | (M: 74 V:4) | (M: 61 V:4)] Empty: 1
[(M: 18 V:3) | (M: 82 V:6) | (M: 40 V:4) | (M: 100 V:6)] Empty: 1
[(M: 7 V:6) | (M: 65 V:7)] Empty: 7
[(M: 37 V:8) | (M: 23 V:3) | (M: 28 V:4)] Empty: 5
[(M: 23 V:8) | (M: 39 V:6) | (M: 13 V:2)] Empty: 4
[(M: 6 V:7) | (M: 16 V:4)] Empty: 9
[(M: 76 V:10) | (M: 3 V:5)] Empty: 5
```

You do not need to use classes and functions at all, you could just use tuples and lambdas but this way it should be clear what does what ...